# DRF Form Rendered in SPA

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to wrap my head around the workings of DRF and I just cannot understand how to achieve this or even where to start with understanding the flow of things.

I'm trying to render an HTML form out of DRF to an SPA or static HTML page with JQuery.

I have a page /page/

I have a serializer:

```
`class StudentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      class Meta: 
      model = Student fields = ('firstName', 'lastName')`
```

Now I need to have a form rendered that has the initial data and allows to POST/PUT.

I can do this very successfully with an APIView and HTMLrenderer, but I’m trying to see if I can have multiple rendered forms on a single page without a single APIView page.

If the general approach is to hand-code the forms on a SPA front-end then that’s great, I just want to know if that’s the required approach.

Comment: Forms don't really fit into DRF. you use Forms with like jinja in traditional web. DRF is for building a rest API that accepts and returns JSON/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to get at. So generally, all form rendering and error-handling is done on the front-end, then?

Comment: yes. your front and back ends are intentionally decoupled